# how do i add the value from the input field as the amount of list items to be added in a ul jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I want to add the amount put in a input field to a ul as list items.
I tried this but i can't come further then this:

```
<body>
<input type="text" name="" id="txtNaam" placeholder="voer een getal in">
<div id="divResult"></div>
<ul></ul>
<script>
    $(document).ready(() => {
        var txtNaam = $('#txtNaam')
        $(document).on('click', function () {
            txtNaam.on('keypress', function (e) {
                var key = e.which
                if (key === 13) {
                    $('ul').append('<li>' + txtNaam.val() + '</li>');
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
</body>
```

So with txtNaam.val() if i write like 3 eggs for example in the txtNaam input field then eggs is added 3 times, is what i want to do.

Thanks already!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  `Regular Expressions` to extract number string from the input value. Then parse it to `int` and use a `for` loop to carry the duplication.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
  var txtNaam = $('#txtNaam');
  let numb;
    txtNaam.on('change', () => {
    if(txtNaam.val().match(/\d+/)!=null){
 numb = parseInt(txtNaam.val().match(/\d+/)[0]);
  }});
  txtNaam.on('keyup', function(e) {

    var key = e.which;
    if (key === 13) {
      if (numb >= 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < numb; i++) {
          $('ul').append(`<li style="text-transform: capitalize;">  ${txtNaam.val().replace(numb, '')}  </li>`);
        }
        numb=0;
      }
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input " type="text" name="txtNaam" id="txtNaam" placeholder="voer een getal in">
<div id="divResult"></div>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer! but is it possible to do it trough one enter click?

Comment: thanks for the reply, how do i add it without the number showing in the list?

Comment: @user22934804 Even if you enter whitespace in the input field and hit the enter key, the code will run and an error will occur, so you will have to maintain validation.

Comment: what does maintain validation mean and how do i do it? also how do i add the lists without the number showing in the lists?

Comment: thanks allot for the answer, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```js
  $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#txtNaam').on('keypress', function (e) {
          var txtNaam = $.trim(parseInt($('#txtNaam').val()));
          var key = e.which
          if (key === 13 && txtNaam != '') {
          for(var y = 0; y < txtNaam; y++){
            $('ul').append('<li></li>');
          }
         }
      });
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="txtNaam" id="txtNaam" placeholder="voer een getal in">
<div id="divResult"></div>
<ul></ul>
```

Comment: thank u for the answer, but its not working it just adds the input field value but not the amount times thats put into the input field. if for example i put 3 eggs then eggs is added 3 times as a list item is what i want to accomplish.

Comment: @user22934804  I have just updated my answer, now you can check it.

Comment: @user22934804 Try this code. you can add the lists without the number showing in the lists.

Comment: thanks for the answer, appreciate it!